# В slick slider не отображается текст

Tags: slick.js

При вставке текста на слайд, почему-то отображается только первый пункт с тегом

. Следующие, которые идут за ним, не отображаются вообще. Причем в инспекторе кода на странице видно, что они прогрузились в html, но самих их не видно. пробовала z-index, не помогло.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mainSlider').slick({
                dots: true,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slideToScroll: 1,
            })
    })
</script>
```

```css
.topSlider {
    height: 676px;
    position: relative;
}
.mainSlider {
    height: 100%;
}
.slide__info {
    height: 100%;
}
.slide {
    background: url('../img/slide 1@2x.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    &__overHeader{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 55px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-top: 130px;
    }
} 
.slick-list, .slick-list * {
    height: 100%;
}
.slick-dots {
    bottom: 127px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider mainSlider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row slide__info">
                <p class="slide__overHeader">Коллекция</p>
                <p class="slide__header">Осень-Зима 18-19</p>
                <p class="slide__text">Производство и оптовая продажа женской одежды.
                    <br>Качественная брендовая одежда по хорошим ценам.</p>
                <a href="#" class="slide__button" type="button">Перейти в каталог</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide__info">
                        <p class="slide__overHeader">Коллекция</p>
                        <p class="slide__header">Осень-Зима 18-19</p>
                        <p class="slide__text">Производство и оптовая продажа женской одежды.
                            <br>Качественная брендовая одежда по хорошим ценам.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="slide__button" type="button">Перейти в каталог</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide__info">
                        <p class="slide__overHeader">Коллекция</p>
                        <p class="slide__header">Осень-Зима 18-19</p>
                        <p class="slide__text">Производство и оптовая продажа женской одежды.
                            <br>Качественная брендовая одежда по хорошим ценам.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="slide__button" type="button">Перейти в каталог</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Вот, видно только коллекцию, а то, что идет в разметке после нее, не отображается. В чем может быть проблема?]

Comment: Еще заметно, что когда страница только прогружается, этот текст появляется на секунду, потом пропадает

Answer (score 0):

Все видно:

```js
$('.mainSlider').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slideToScroll: 1,
});
```

```css
.topSlider {
    height: 676px;
    position: relative;
}
.mainSlider {
    height: 100%;
}
.slide__info {
    height: 100%;
}
.slide {
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526542215298-3ef7ea699e99?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
} 

.slide__overHeader{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 130px;
}
.slick-list, .slick-list * {
    height: 100%;
}
.slick-dots {
    bottom: 127px;
}



.row.slide__info {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="slider mainSlider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row slide__info">
                <p class="slide__overHeader">Коллекция</p>
                <p class="slide__header">Осень-Зима 18-19</p>
                <p class="slide__text">Производство и оптовая продажа женской одежды.
                    <br>Качественная брендовая одежда по хорошим ценам.</p>
                <a href="#" class="slide__button" type="button">Перейти в каталог</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide__info">
                        <p class="slide__overHeader">Коллекция</p>
                        <p class="slide__header">Осень-Зима 18-19</p>
                        <p class="slide__text">Производство и оптовая продажа женской одежды.
                            <br>Качественная брендовая одежда по хорошим ценам.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="slide__button" type="button">Перейти в каталог</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide__info">
                        <p class="slide__overHeader">Коллекция</p>
                        <p class="slide__header">Осень-Зима 18-19</p>
                        <p class="slide__text">Производство и оптовая продажа женской одежды.
                            <br>Качественная брендовая одежда по хорошим ценам.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="slide__button" type="button">Перейти в каталог</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```